# How to remove element from a String with Int index

Tags: swift, string, integer

I'm trying to count identical elements in two strings by comparing them in Int range. I solved the issue of subscripting, but I'm now getting an "extra" element. Here's my code:

```
 func getResult(s: String, k: Int, stringGoal: String) -> Int {
        
        var identiticalSymbols = 0
        var deletionsLimit = k
        var string = s
        
        if string.count <= 19, deletionsLimit <= 9{
            for i in 0...string.count-1 {
                
                if string[i] == stringGoal[i] {
                    identiticalSymbols += i
                }
                
                else {
                    string.remove(at: String.Index(utf16Offset: i, in: string))
                    
                    deletionsLimit -= 1
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        return identiticalSymbols
    }
}

extension String {
   
    subscript(_ i: Int) -> String {
        let idx1 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
       
        return String(self[idx1..<endIndex])
      }
    
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound)
        return String(self[start ..< end])
      }


}
```

My input:

```
let result = getResult(s: "agdd", k: 4, stringGoal: "gdd")
```

`s` is initial string, `k` is deletion limit and `goalString` is string for comparison.

I'm getting 6 identical symbols instead of 3

Comment: What is `s`? What is `k`? What is `stringGoal`? You'd need to include these to have a [mre].

Comment: @jnpdx k is deletion limit, s is initial string, and stringGoal is a string for comparison. They're function parameters, that's why I initialized new properties

Comment: can you give an input and expected output?

Comment: You need to include the declarations of `s`, `k`, and `stringGoal` in your question, along with the declaration of your `getResult(s:k:stringGoal:)` function. If `s` is a `String` then your code `string[i]` won't compile without you creating an extension to String that allows an Integer subscript. But beware, because of the way Unicode works, using an Integer index into a String requires parsing the entire string from the beginning, making it and `O(n)` operation. Looping through a `String` by Int index then becomes an `O(n²)` operation, which is bad.

Comment: @DuncanC I tried to replace for in loop with enumerated().forEach, but it produces error that value of type Int can't convert to String.Index

Comment: the duplications of the string need to be in the same position or you only want to know the character that are repeating in any position?

Comment: @ИванМаслов you can select your code in Xcode and use "CTRL-i" to format it -- it'll help readability significantly.

Comment: Your extension to String is a bad idea. As mentioned, it will have `O(n)` performance, so using it to loop through a string character by character will have `O(n²)` performance.

Comment: You say "I'm trying to count identical elements in two strings by comparing them in Int range..." What does that mean? Deletion limit? Huh? It is not at all clear what you're trying to calculate. You need to explain it clearly before we can help you implement it.

Comment: @DuncanC it means, that in case that if strings have identical element, identical symbols are incremented by one. If not, deletionLimit is decreased and element is removed from the array at that index. But I want to use Int index

Comment: @cristian_064 at the same

Comment: @jnpdx updated.

Comment: @DuncanC if I remove extension, compiler will give me a subscript error

Comment: Correct. You should either learn how to implement your task using String.Index, or convert your string to an Array of Characters and then subscript into that. (Converting a String to an Array of Chars takes `O(n)` time, but then operations on the Array run in fixed time, avoiding the `O(n²)` performance problem.

Comment: What is an "identical element?" A single character? A sequence of characters?

Comment: @DuncanC, same character at specified index in both strings

Comment: I give up. You keep giving little bits of the description of your problem without giving enough info for your readers to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DuncanC what more info do you neeed?

Comment: @DuncanC hello! Could you help me with the task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744324/fatal-error-index-out-of-range-file-swift-contiguousarraybuffer ?

Answer (score 1):

I have this code but I'm not using the k, I'm counting the repetitions and remove the repetitions that I already count.

```
func getRepetitions(firstString: String, comparativeString: String) -> Int {
    var repetitions = 0
    var comparativeStringName = Array(comparativeString)
    for character in firstString {
        if comparativeStringName.contains(character),
           let index = comparativeStringName.firstIndex(of: character){
            comparativeStringName.remove(at: index)
            repetitions += 1
        }
    }
    return repetitions
}
```

Comment: @christian_064 thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

It helped me.

func getResult(s: String, k: Int, stringGoal: String) -> Int {

```
    var identiticalSymbols = 0
    var deletionsLimit = k
```

var string = s

```
    if string.count <= 19, deletionsLimit <= 9{
        for i in 0...string.count-1 {
            if string[i] == stringGoal[i] {
                identiticalSymbols += 1
            }
            else {
                string.remove(at: String(string[i]).startIndex)
              
                deletionsLimit -= 1
            }
        }
        
    }
return identiticalSymbols
}
```

}

extension String {

```
var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[0 ..< max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: min(length, max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
}
```

}