# Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to solve a task in such a way that victims with largest amount of money get robbed first, then poorest get their share. But when I come to multiplying poor's wealth, I get the described error. With forEach method this error doesn't appear, but it exits after first completion of guard statement. Here's the code:

```
//Input
let result = getResult(passersby: [3, 10, 4, 8])
```

/// Transfer money from rich to poor with retaining largest portion of it by yourself. Poor's income should increase in 2 times. Each toperation could be performed to a person ones.

```
func getResult(passersby: [Int]) -> Int {

    var victims = passersby
    var profit = 0
    
    
    for i in 0...(victims.enumerated().reversed()).count-1 {
        
        if victims.count > 0 && victims.count <= 10, victims[i] > 0 && victims[i] <= 1000{
            
            if victims[i] == victims.max() {
                profit += victims[i]
                victims.remove(at: i)
            }
            guard profit > victims.min()! && !victims.contains(victims.max()!) else { continue }
          
            profit -= victims[i != victims.endIndex ? i : victims.first!]
            victims[i] *= 2
            victims.remove(at: i)
         }           
    }      
    
    return profit
}
```

---

Here's what I get in the console.[image]

How can I make the loop iterate until the last index included?

Comment: There is an iron rule: Don't modify the size of an array while being enumerated. At the moment you remove an item from the array the index count-1 doesn't exist anymore and the loop runs out of range eventually.

Comment: @vadian I had the same problem without sorted and enumerated. But I read that it could prevent getting index out of bounds since we remove index from the end of the array.

Comment: Actually you don't *remove index from the end of the array*. `victims.enumerated().reversed().count` is pointless. It's exactly the same as `victims.count`. The loop is enumerated in ascending order starting with 0

Comment: @vadim range 0..<victims.endIndex doesn't work either. But I see

Comment: Iterating backwards is `for i in victims.indices.reversed()`

Comment: @vadian thank you. The error disappeared, but result didn't change

Comment: @vadian question was updated

Answer (score 1):

The task is not really clear, but to avoid such errors you could apply a more functional approach

```
let passersBy: [Int] = [3, 10, 4, 8]
var sortedPassers = [Int](passersBy.sorted().reversed())
let poorest = sortedPassers.removeLast()
let profit = sortedPassers.reduce(0, +)
```

could post the text of the exercise so it would be easier to help finding a solution

Comment: thank you. I would to try to clarify the task though. victims[i] is amount of money which every victim has. I want to execute the task in such way, that we take the largest sum to our pockets and then increase welfare of poorest in 2 times, while retaining the largest portion of money. And function should return how much money was retained